# Using YAML data in Ruby App

Tags: ruby, yaml

I want to load data from my YAML file and use the it in my ruby application. The contents available in YAML will be used in different places. Therefore, I want to read it initially and use the data whenever required.

I would like to know what is the best practice for this?

What I tried is

config.yaml

```
db:
 username: admin
 password: admin
```

config.rb

```
class Config
 class << self
    attr_accessor :uname, :pwd
    def load
       config_data = YAML.load_file("c:\config.yml")
       @uname = config_data['db']['username']
       @pwd = config_data['db']['password']
    end
 end
end
```

my_app.rb

```
Config.load
puts Config.uname
puts Config.pwd
```

Please let me know whether this is a right way to load and use YAML data. If not please share the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hardly depends on your intentions, but generally speaking, yes, it is *mostly* correct approach. What do you want to do more, is to cache once read data:

```
class Config
 class << self
    attr_accessor :uname, :pwd
    def load force_reload = false
       return @config_data if @config_data && !force_reload

       @config_data = YAML.load_file("c:\config.yml")
       @uname = @config_data['db']['username']
       @pwd = @config_data['db']['password']
    end
 end
end
```

Here we return immediately, if the `@config` was already loaded, allowing fast subsequent calls to `Config.config`.

Whether one wants to explicitly reload the config, it should pass the parameter to load:

```
Config.load true # true means reload YAML explicitly
```